# Outputting MVC ViewBag text with some areas not encoded?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following example:

```
<div>@ViewBag.MyData</div>
```

What to do if ViewBag.MyData contains a string with "\n" (newlines) in it, that I want to change into "`<br/>`"? When I include "`<br/>`" instead of the newlines, it gets encoded in the browser, which is bad.

How can I help this?

Comment: Perform the replacement within the razor template. `@ViewBag.MyData.Replace("\n","<br />")` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyData.Replace("\n", "</br>"))`

Comment: Kind of not that smart to mention things like "above". Now your answer is the top-most answer.

Comment: But remember, that now this text is not encoded, so if ViewBag.MyData has text generated by user, it could contain injections... Maybe better would be split string and write encoded string parts with not encoded "</br>" parts..

Answer (score 5):

the following will do what you need...

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.MyData.Replace("\n", "</br>"))
```

The `Create` method will take a HTML string and render it as would be expected if you just typed the HTML straight onto the page

Answer (score 2):

That's what [html pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) is used for

> The < pre> tag defines preformatted text. Text in a < pre> element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks ...

And in razor template

```
< pre>@ViewBag.MyData</ pre>
```